# Should I give params to the constructor or to AsyncTask.execute(params)?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to figure out why Android's AsyncTask gives parameters through `execute` and why passing then to the constructor doesn't seem to be done (in the docs, at least).

This is the way that seems to me to make the most sense (naturally, the actual task I'm working with is more than just a sum calculator):

```
public class FooTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Long> {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int[] data;

    public FooTask(ProgressBar progressBar, int... data) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.data = data;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setMax(data.length);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
    }

    protected Long doInBackground(Void... _) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sum += data[i];
            publishProgress(i);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Sum: " + result);
    }
}
```

This would be used thus:

```
new FooTask(progressBar, 1, 2, 3).execute();
```

However, this isn't the way the documentation talks about doing it; it uses arguments to `execute()`, like this (taken to the extreme of not using a constructor at all, but still using one field because otherwise it'd be too horrible):

```
public class FooTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Long> {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private boolean isMaxSettingUpdate = true;

    protected Long doInBackground(Object... params) {
        progressBar = params[0];
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            sum += (int) data[i];
            publishProgress(i - 1, data.length);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        progressBar.setMax(progress[1]);
        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Sum: " + result);
    }
}
```

Execution of this task would look more like this:

```
new FooTask().execute(progressBar, 1, 2, 3);
```

One other option I considered was giving the progress bar to the constructor and the data to the execute call, but then I still can't use `onPreExecute` as I don't know the max value. (I would prefer to use a true max rather than setting the max value arbitrarily and calculating the percentage... just seems nicer.)

Where's the balance? What should I do? Is there anything *wrong* with using the constructor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As to why the docs do everything in the method can be as a result of their example choice. Usually, you're more likely to extend your AsyncTask and only use `doInBackground()`, not the constructor.

Anyways, the [documentation states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> Memory observability
>
> ---
>
> AsyncTask guarantees that all callback calls are synchronized in such
>   a way that the following operations are safe without explicit
>   synchronizations.
>
> •Set member fields *in the constructor* or onPreExecute(), and refer to them in          > doInBackground(Params...).
>
> •Set member fields in doInBackground(Params...), and refer to them in
>   onProgressUpdate(Progress...) and onPostExecute(Result).

This means that you should be good with both approaches.

And as a side note, I have used an `AsyncTask` with a param-ed constructor without issues, so I can back up what the documentation states.

Also, for your specific case, unless the `ProgressBar` has had a different max value set beforehand, it should default to 100. This means that you can have your constructor accept in just the `ProgressBar` and have `doInBackground()` accept in the data (which should also be a member variable). Then when updating the progress, do

```
(progress[0]/data.length) * 100
```

It won't be perfect, and you can convert to double if you want to increase accuracy, but this should make the code easiest to understand.

Comment: How would you go about the progress bar thing? Is it appropriate to be passing it like that?

Comment: Since you do need `onPreExecute()`, I'd go with your first, constructor only approach, it satisfies the requirement and it's easier to read. You will have to watch out for orientation changes though. Since Activities/Fragments do get recreated, your Task will be holding on to an old reference of the progress bar if that happens, so the bar shouldn't update for the user.

Comment: Oh! Shows how little I understand how Android works internally. It had never occurred to me to think other than that they would be the same object before and after. I see thus that passing the progress bar is *not* safe. Thanks for clearing that!

Comment: @ChrisMorgan no problem :-) As for thinking about orientation changes and AsyncTasks, [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/4dW4-KMUKJI) provides some options, but some searching should show more as well.

Comment: My eventual solution has been to pass messages back to the activity via an intent—I hadn't been thinking clearly when thinking I could use the progress bar directly, for the AsyncTask was actually being run from a service. Anyhow, I did finally get it all working as I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, if I want to pass some values to initial the UI, just like ProgressBar you mentioned, I need do it in `OnPreExecute()`. And because the `OnPreExecute()` don't accept any parameters, I prefer to put values in constructor as a parameters. If some values are not relative to UI, just need in `doInBackground`, for example, the download urls of files, I will pass them as parameters of execute.

So, in a summary, if the values are about UI, pass them in constructor,
if values are just used in doInBackground, pass them as parameters of execute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do work (that requires parameters) on the main-thread, you have to pass those parameters to the constructor.

Everything you pass via .execute() will be run on the async-thread.

As buptcoder mentioned, mainly that will concern UI stuff, but also disk/database operations can be thread-critical