# Passing data to AsyncTask: execute(args) vs constructor?

Tags: android, constructor, android-asynctask

in my projects I'm using lots of `AsyncTask`s. All they send some data via http to a server. In some of them I pass the data vie `execute( data... )`. In others I'm using constructor for that:

```
new SomeTask().execute( 1, 2, 3 );
```

or

```
new SomeOtherTask( 1, 2, 3 ).execute();
```

Basically those calls are equivalent, as the `AsyncTask` cannot be re-used and is stateless.

What is the preferable way to use those? Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I give params to the constructor or to AsyncTask.execute(params)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765415/should-i-give-params-to-the-constructor-or-to-asynctask-executeparams)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, pass parameters to the `execute` method (if they all share the same type, off course). Using a custom constructor forces you to write it and store parameters in private variables, which is useless, unless these parameters are used in the `OnPostExecute` method for instance.

Comment: yepp, that's also the case, about `onPre/PostExecute`. for example, in `pre` I show the progressBar, in `post` I hide it

Comment: Parameters could be seen as transitory data, they are only used by doInBackground, as input, nothing more. It these parameters are more valuable, if their scope exceed doInBackground, they must be a part of the task and set in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use `new SomeTask().execute( 1, 2, 3 );`

It is better than passing values to constructor. If you pass your input as argument to constructor, you will need to create member variables and that will be superfluous, since AsyncTask allow us pass variable arguments in execute method.

Until  and unless there is need to maintain member variables for the input passed to AsyncTask, constructor should not be used to pass input.