# AsyncTask - How can i pass an object as parameter to an anonymous AsyncTask class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am doing some coding stuff with android. Nearly I faced a problem and to solve this I need an **anonymous** *AsyncTask* class to execute. But I also need to pass and object to this class before execution. I tried the below code but it's not working and I did not find any solution by googling also.

```
 public void saveCartToRoom(CartsPay cartsPay){

    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

        CartsPay cartsPay;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return null;
        }

        public void setRQ(CartsPay cartsPay){
            this.cartsPay= cartsPay;
        }

    }.setRQ(cartsPay).execute();

}
```

Comment: Why do you nees it to be anonymous ?

Comment: Usually you want to add an attribute and provide the value using the constructor.

Comment: I need to do some background things which will not interrupt my running UI thread.

Comment: how can I do that with an anonymous class, I mean the constructor things?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765415/should-i-give-params-to-the-constructor-or-to-asynctask-executeparams

Comment: In any case I don't understand the anonymous requirement.

Comment: just for reducing some extra code lines in the project

Comment: You can't use constructors on anonymous classes: "However, you cannot declare constructors in an anonymous class." from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html. So it's up to you if you prefer to avoid some extra lines (you can use the doInBackground parameters)  or if you prefer to follow conventions and create a normal class

Comment: but I can create methods inside an anonymous class like Getter or Setter method.
So how can I call the Setter method before the execution of that task?

Comment: An easy way is to return "this" from the setter. But I'd prefer to avoid the anonymous thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to pass a `CartsPay` parameter to an **anonymous**`AsyncTask`

```
new AsyncTask<CartsPay,Void,Void>(){

        CartsPay cartsPay;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(CartsPay... params) {

            this.cartsPay = params[0];

            // Your code ...

            return null;
        }

        public AsyncTask setRQ(CartsPay cartsPay){
            this.cartsPay= cartsPay;
            return this;
        }

    }.execute(cartsPay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it like that:

```
 class CustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private YourParam mParam;

    public CustomAsyncTask(YourParam param) {
       mParam = param;
    } 

    @Override
    protected doInBackground(Void.. voids){
      //do your thing.
    }
}
```

And then using it:

```
new CustomAsyncTask(param).execute();
```